# Getting Opera and Safari to play sounds

Tags: html, html5-audio

I have used the following html audio tags to plays different files in different sound formats

```
<audio controls="player_1">
<source src="D:\HND grrrrr\Year_2\RoyWebsite\Sounds\WAV\home_page_readout.wav"       type="audio/wav"/>
<source src="D:\HND grrrrr\Year_2\RoyWebsite\Sounds\MP3\home_page_readout.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
<source src="D:\HND grrrrr\Year_2\RoyWebsite\Sounds\ogg\home_page_readout.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
</audio>
```

Now the right sound format plays in IE and Chrome, however when i open the page up in Opera or Safari, the sound player appaears but the play button does not work when it is pressed, as if the file cannot be found or something ?

Oh and I don't know what the type/ part is so separated on the first line

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative path or even move the files to some web server. That should be it.
And obviously - update your browser.

BTW: There are some html5 features (like desktop notifications) which won't work locally at all.

Comment: so how would i cut the link down to that its a relative path, so would that be something like     \Year_2\RoyWebsite\Sounds\WAV\home_page_readout.wav for example

Comment: Yes, exactly. if you put the audio file in the same directory as the .html file you can simply type the name of the file as src.
Try this one :)